# How to convert a string containing only 0 or 1 into a binary variable？

Tags: c++, string, binary, decimal, radix

How to convert a C++ string (containing only "0" or "1") to binary data directly according to its literal value?

For example, I have a string `str`, it's value is `0010010`. Now I want to convert this string to a binary form variable, or a decimal variable equal to `0b0010010` (is `18`).

```
int main() {
    string str_1 = "001";
    string str_2 = "0010";
    string str = str_1 + str_2;
    cout << str << endl;

    int i = stoi(str);
    double d = stod(str);
    cout << i << " and " << d << endl;
}
```

I tried `stoi` and `stod`, but they all can't work. They all treated binary `0b0010010` as decimal `10010`. So how can I achieve this requirement? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I tried stoi and stod, but they all can't work"- Ehh, why not? They work just fine for me.

Comment: [Here](https://cplusplus.com/reference/string/stoi/) is an example of using `stoi` to convert a binary string.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`std::stoi`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stol) has an optional second argument to give you information about where the parsing stopped, and *an optional third argument for passing the base of the conversion*.

```
int i = stoi(str, nullptr, 2);
```

This should work.

---

Corollary: If in doubt, check the documentation. ;-)

Comment: Thank you very much! I didn't read the documentation carefully, this is my fault. I will pay more attention next time! Thanks!